# Virtual KeyCode Asterisk key

Tags: c#, keyboard, keycode

I want to create an onscreen keyboard but I don't know what is keycode of asterisk/star key (in numpad scope). Can anyone help me.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to check it, is if you attach Key Press event against a text box and in the event you put a break point to see what is being returned against `*` asterisk. Its value is:

```
e = {KeyChar = 42 '*'}
```

Comment: Thank Habib, I have found it. It's MULTIPLY VirtualKeyCode

Comment: Looks like `VirtualKey.Multiply` is *only* the `*` on the num pad. You can inelegantly get `*` via `case VirtualKey.Number8: if (shift.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)) {...`, but that's heavily keyboard layout specific.